How can I turn off "Firmware update available" notifications on Ubuntu 23.10+?
I already tried turning them off under Settings > Notifications, with no avail. It still appears every 3 hours.

Solution
sudo snap stop --disable firmware-updater.firmware-notifier

Details
It seems these notifications are sent by Firmware Updater, which is a snap app. I tried stopping and disabling fwupd as Lefty suggested but it didn't work. The next time Firmware Updater runs, it will start fwupd and the notification will appear.
You could potentially mask fwupd so the service can't be started at all, but then I don't think Firmware Updater would work at all.
So apparently snap applications have their own services, and by running the command above it disabled the service responsible for these notifications:
$ snap services
Service                                              Startup   Current   Notes
firmware-updater.firmware-notifier                   disabled  inactive  user,timer-activated
firmware-updater.firmware-updater-app                enabled   inactive  user,dbus-activated

The best part is Firmware Updater still seems to work if I open it manually.

Thank you, it worked! I had to reinstall Firmware Updater first, as I uninstalled it previously - although it solved the issue, I preferred a solution where I don't need to uninstall the tool - and test it. I turned off the service as suggested, and the notifications stopped. Canonical needs to have a better solution though.

If you're not interested in firmware updates, you can disable the whole firmware update service using:
sudo systemctl disable fwupd fwupd-refresh.timer
sudo systemctl stop fwupd

Note that you can still refresh firmware database or update firmware manually, eg. using fwupdtool.

This doesn't seem to work. After reboot, fwupd is enabled again. I'm not sure what's enabling it.
